# How to copy an image from one worksheet to another WITHOUT using select

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it's possible to move an image from one worksheet to another (in the same workbook) without having to select cells. My current solution (obviously using copy and paste) is as follows:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Assets").Shapes("logo").Cut 'Destination:=Worksheets("test").Range("$A$1")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("$A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
```

Specifying a 'Desitation' parameter doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You were not so far from functional in your initial code.  You could cut and paste without selecting like this:

```
Sub CutPaste()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Assets").Shapes("logo").Cut
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did this recently where I had a number of pics on one sheet needed to find the correct one then insert it on another sheet. I did it this way without selecting any cells.

```
 Dim teamShape As Shape
 Dim reportSheet As Worksheet: Set reportSheet = Sheets("Iteration Report")
 Dim picSheet As Worksheet: Set picSheet = Sheets("Pics")

 For Each teamShape In picSheet.Shapes
     If teamShape.AlternativeText = PicName Then
        teamShape.CopyPicture
        reportSheet.Range("h27").PasteSpecial
        Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 175.937480315
        Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -4.687480315
        Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 300
        Exit For
     End If
  Next teamShape
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I then reference the pasted image so that I can change things like its .top and .left properties?

Comment: I will change my answer above to include some of that which I did, hopefully it will give a better idea